# c# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" on empty Array

Tags: c#

I get error

> "'Index was outside the bounds of the array"

on this line `string Open = array[0].ToString();` when array is empty.

I used **"if"** statement to see if it can be by-passed when array is empty.

However, why am I still getting this error? How can I by-pass/fix it?

```
if (array != null || array.Length != 0)
                {
                    int c = array.Count();
                    string Open = array[0].ToString(); <--- ERROR
                }
```

Comment: can you show us your array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You used the logical OR operator in your if statement. You should have used the AND operator `&&`.

OR will evaluate to true if any of the two conditions is true, so your if statement will be run as long as `array` is not null.

It should be:

```
if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

This must be

```
if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
if (array != null || array.Length != 0)
```

to

```
if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The **IndexOutOfRangeException** is a Runtime Exception thrown only at runtime.

According to your question, it seems like you should use check for null and length together as said by others

```
if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
```

but because you have not marked any answer as accepted so I must tell you to put your code within try and catch block like below

```
  try
  {
      if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
      {
         int c = array.Count();
         string Open = array[0].ToString(); <--- ERROR
      }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      // Put breakpoint here and see inner exception by hovering your mouse cursor over ex.
  }
```

You will get more details in inner exception on such issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can check an empty array's length. However, if you try to do that on a null reference you'll get an exception. Here you need && condition which will check for null and array length,

```
if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
```